# using broadcast recevire with alarm manager in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, intentservice

Why is it suggested generally to pass a pending intent for an Intent Service when using alarm manager? The same thing can be done in the onreceive() function of the broadcast receiver called by the alarmmanager. What is the advantage with using a service(Intent Service)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything that you need done can be completed in `onReceive` of a `BroadcastReceiver`, then you should use that, not an `IntentService`.

If you want to do anything after the `BroadcastReceiver`, then you should use the `IntentService`. For example, if you want your `BroadcastReceiver` to start a `Service`, and you want the service to gain a `WakeLock`, then you should be using an `IntentService` instead.

The reason is that `AlarmManager` only guarantees that the `onReceive` of a `BroadcastReceiver` will be run, even if you use `RTC_WAKEUP`. So, it is slightly possible that if you use the `BroadcastReceiver`/`Service` combination, then the CPU will fall asleep before the `Service` can acquire the `WakeLock` - this is, unless you acquire a `WakeLock` in the `BroadcastReceiver` and you acquire one in the service, perhaps via a `static` `WakeLock`. But this is... messy, I suppose.

Btw, I have never implemented an `IntentService`. I just use the `BroadcastReceiver` and `Service` combo and have never had a problem reported. All the information I provided are things I read from other SO posts (primarily from CommonsWare)

**EDIT:**

The 50ms time frame I read from something CommonsWare posted on StackOverflow, and CommonsWare seems to be a rather reliable source of knowledge for Android.

I looked it up and, [The docs](http://goo.gl/jd6jf) do say:

> (there is a timeout of 10 seconds that the system allows before
>   considering the receiver to be blocked and a candidate to be killed).

And they also say:

> If this BroadcastReceiver was launched through a  tag, then the object is no
>   longer alive after returning from this function.

1. You should not do anything that takes close to 10 seconds, just to be safe.
2. If you do anything that has to wait for a response, the `BroadcastReceiver` will die because the `onReceive` will likely finish running before you get the response back.

Though, I suppose the reason for the 50ms time frame is so you don't risk causing an ANR or any lag. Because if you use a `Service`, then you can start a new `Thread`, and it will not block. You would not be able to start a new `Thread` in a `BroadcastReceiver` because the code after the thread would continue to run, the `BroadcastReceiver` would die, and then the `Thread` would die, too.

Comment: What I am asking is what will a service be able to do that a broadcast receiver cannot?

Comment: If you have to do something that takes more than 50 ms, you should use a `Service` because `BroadcastReceiver`s are short lived. So for something like polling from a server, or sending a text message and checking the status of it, or playing audio, for example, you would need a `Service`.

Comment: What do you mean by broadcast receivers are shortlived? Will it die before finishing the job?

Comment: Yes. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958248/android-alarm-died-during-onreceive/9958927). If you have any code that is long running, you need to use a `Service`. Though, don't underestimate the speed of the code to run. If you have a lot of code, put a `Log.i(tag, "beginning)` right at the top of the `onReceive`, and then an "end" `Log` right at the end of `onReceive. Compare the times via the `Logcat`. If the difference in time is < 50ms, then use the `BroadcastReceiver`.
If you use any code that requires your app to wait for any amount of time, just use a `Service`

Comment: Where is it given that Broadcast receiver dies within 50 ms. It is not mentioned in android docs.

Comment: Okay thank you. But still the 50ms is somewhat misleading, Since it is given as 10 secs in docs.

Comment: I know. I understand why you say that. The 50 ms is not something I made up. It's something I read from an answer CommonsWare gave some time back. Either way, if you have, for example, a `while` loop that loops infinitely for 8 seconds, it will probably cause an ANR, and a "force close" dialog will appear. (I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure that would happen). That's just an example I'm giving to say that if you leave the `BroadcastReceiver` running code for long at all, the user might notice lag in the phone, which we want to avoid at all cost.